# issue with warnings.filterwarning (with minimal reproducible you know)

Tags: python, regex, warnings

I can't understand what's wrong with the following code:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='frequency information was provided')
warnings.warn("No frequency information was provided, so inferred frequency MS will be used.")
```

Why does the warning pass the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `filterwarnings` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings):

> This checks the types of the arguments, compiles the message and module regular expressions, and inserts them as a tuple in the list of warnings filters.

The `message` argument is a *regular expression*. It matches the *biginning* of your message. However, if you change the `filterwarnings` statement to:

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='.*frequency information was provided')
```

the message will match your warning and the warning will be ignored.

Comment: I knew it was a regular expression, but I didn't catch the "beginning" part, that was a surprise

Answer (score 0):

The `message` of a warning filter is a case-insensitive regular expression that the **start** of a warning message must match for the filter to apply.

`'frequency information was provided'` does not match the **start** of `"No frequency information was provided, so inferred frequency MS will be used."`,